# Show replace panel on click monaco editor

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

I'm creating an app using monaco-editor. I wanna show the replace panel when I click on a button. I searched a lot but I didn't find what I wanted. I tried that :

```
  window.editor.focus();
  window.editor.getAction('actions.replace').run()
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the replace panel use the action `editor.action.startFindReplaceAction`.

```
editor.getAction('editor.action.startFindReplaceAction').run()
```

If you want list of all the actions available then use the method `editor.getActions()` which will give the list of all available actions.

Comment: Thank you very much.